# MYSQL databases sum function

Tags: mysql

```
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| contribution   |
| expectedamount |
| registration   |
+----------------+

registration table
+----+--------+-------------+
| id | reg_no | fullname    |
+----+--------+-------------+
|  1 | TTI001 | JOHN JAMES  |
|  2 | TTI002 | DAVID CERES |
|  3 | TTI003 | JOYCE LEE   |
|  4 | TTI004 | JOEL MARTIN |
+----+--------+-------------+

espectedamount
+----+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| id | reg_no | number1 | number2 | number3 |
+----+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 | TTI001 |     500 |     500 |     500 |
|  2 | TTI002 |     500 |     500 |     500 |
|  3 | TTI003 |     500 |     500 |     500 |
|  4 | TTI004 |     500 |     500 |     500 |
|  5 | TTI001 |     400 |     400 |     400 |
|  6 | TTI001 |    1000 |    1000 |    1000 |
|  7 | TTI002 |    1000 |    1000 |    1000 |
|  8 | TTI003 |    1000 |    1000 |    1000 |
|  9 | TTI004 |    1000 |    1000 |    1000 |
+----+--------+---------+---------+---------+

contribution table
+----+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| id | reg_no | number1 | number2 | number3 |
+----+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 | TTI001 |     200 |     400 |     600 |
|  2 | TTI002 |     100 |      50 |     250 |
|  3 | TTI001 |     100 |     400 |     400 |
|  4 | TTI002 |     300 |     400 |     600 |
|  5 | TTI003 |     300 |     100 |      50 |
|  6 | TTI004 |      50 |      60 |      40 |
|  7 | TTI004 |     500 |     300 |     400 |
+----+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I created the following Query to join tables registration,expectedamaount,and contribution where i WANT TO SUBTRACT SUM FORM amount table from sum contribution table but am getting Wrong result

```
select registration.reg_no
      ,registration.fullname
      ,sum(expectedamount.number1-contribution.number1) as contribution1
      ,sum(expectedamount.number2-contribution.number2) as contribution2
      ,sum(expectedamount.number3-contribution.number3) as contribution3 
FROM registration
INNER JOIN expectedamount ON registration.reg_no = expectedamount.reg_no 
INNER JOIN contribution ON expectedamount.reg_no = contribution.reg_no
GROUP BY reg_no;

+--------+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| reg_no | fullname    | contribution1 | contribution2 | contribution3 |
+--------+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| TTI001 | JOHN JAMES  |           700 |           200 |             0 |
| TTI002 | DAVID CERES |           600 |           550 |           150 |
| TTI003 | JOYCE LEE   |           200 |           400 |           450 |
| TTI004 | JOEL MARTIN |           450 |           640 |           560 |
+--------+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

expected result

```
+-------+---------------+---------------+------------------+--------------+
|reg_no | fullname      | contribution1 | contribution2    | contribution3|
+-------+---------------+---------------+------------------+--------------+
|TTI001 | JOHN JAMES    | 1600          | 1100             |   900        |
|TTI002 | DAVID CERES   | 1000          | 950              |   550        |
|TTI003 | JOYCE LEE     | 1200          | 1400             |   1450       |
|TTI004 | JOEL MARTIN   |  950          | 1140             |   1060       |
+-------+---------------+---------------+------------------+--------------+
```

Kindly guys help.

Comment: This is where you're going wrong: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: my tables are as follows

Comment: Please please please format your question. Otherwise, it will most likely get closed.

Comment: As previously commented, what is the correct result?

Comment: THE ANSWER SHOULD BE TT01 200 -300 -500,TT02 100 50 350,TT02,TT03 200 400 450,TT04 50 140 60

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this -

```
select registration.reg_no
  ,registration.fullname
  ,sum(expected.num1-contrib.num1) as contribution1
  ,sum(expected.num2-contrib.num2) as contribution2
  ,sum(expected.num3-contrib.num3) as contribution3 
FROM registration
INNER JOIN (SELECT reg_no, SUM(number1) num1, SUM(number2) num2, SUM(number3) num3
            FROM expectedamount
            GROUP BY reg_no) expected ON registration.reg_no = expected.reg_no 
INNER JOIN (SELECT reg_no, SUM(number1) num1, SUM(number2) num2, SUM(number3) num3
            FROM contribution
            GROUP BY reg_no) contrib ON expected.reg_no = contrib.reg_no
GROUP BY reg_no;
```

Comment: this is working properly but when I apply it in a tables with alot of data it is not working properly

Comment: Are there some more columns in your table?

Comment: The table am working with has got many column it was supposed to have four which worked property. but I added some which I don't understand why the data they are displaying is incorrect

Comment: the problem happens when an individual has got two or more entries on expectedamount table example if TTI001 has another entry number1 400,number2 400,number3 400 sum is not working on expectedamount table

Comment: this one am stuck totally

Comment: how do i make these sum work on both expectedamount and  contribution

Comment: I think now you should post the better sample data and post your absolute expected result.

Comment: Am still stuck with this query

Comment: I have updated the query to reflect the correct column name.